# Fix bootstrap dropdown menu's behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the html code for the menu at:

https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/img/menufix-ehsan-1.html

There is a problem with the menu, and I don't know how to fix it.  When the viewport is small, the mobile menu (hamburger menu) together with the user-icon shows as desired on the upper right hand corner.

However, when the mobile/hamburger menu is clicked immediately followed by the user-icon image, the mobile menu is not closed, and remains open.  This lead to a poor user experience.  Is there a way to close the mobile/hamburger menu when the user-icon image is clicked immediately after the mobile menu?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Dan

Comment: This is not a very nice piece of code but it may fix your issue in a quick and dirty way: `$(".navbar-brand.user-img").click(function(){
if($("#defaultNavbar1").attr("aria-expanded") == "true") {
$("button.navbar-toggle").click();
}
});`

Comment: What's the expectation for functionality here? You can in your CSS set `nav.open .navbar-collapse.in { display: none }`, but that won't animate the nav opening and closing.

Comment: as a rule you should post all of the relevant code for your question in the "question". if you move or modify that page the question becomes useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made a fiddle for you. Please check if it works the way you wanted to.

```js
(function($) {

  $(".navbar-brand.user-img").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#defaultNavbar1").attr("aria-expanded") === "true") { // if hamburger menu already expanded
      $("button.navbar-toggle").click(); // click hamburger to collapse back
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/content/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default MainMenuBar">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand user-img" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/User.png" class="user-img" /></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li><a id="registerLink" href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Account/Register"><span class="MenuItems">Register</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Account/Login"><span class="MenuItems">Login</span></a> </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.findtaxpro.com"><img class="navbar-brand user-img1" src="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" /></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Marketing/index"><img class="navbar-brand user-img4" src="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/ClickHereArtboard 1-8.png" /></a>


    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
  </div>


  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Search"><span class="MenuItems">Search</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Reviews"><span class="MenuItems">Review</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Search/Promo"><span class="MenuItems">Offers</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Search/Rewards"><span class="MenuItems">Rewards</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Marketing/MileTrack"><span class="MenuItems">MileTrack</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Marketing/ReceiptsandDocs"><span class="MenuItems">Docs</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ihpar.  While the drop-down menus are working as desired, the user-icon has moved to the left from right. I need the user-icon to remain on the right.

Comment: No problem. But I didn't do anything with html or css, so it should stay in its original place. You should just copy paste the javascript code to your source file.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it.  Thanks a lot.  Appreciate it. Dan

Comment: Glad it helped.